# HP Pavillion laptop Sound issue

Tags: windows, audio

I have a HP Pavillion laptop with Windows-7. Recently I has started giving me audio playback problems. I cannot get any audio output from the inbuilt laptop speakers. The audio icon in system tray shows a red cross, it says "No audio output device is installed."

I tried installing the drivers by downloading it from HP support website, but they fail to install and give error Could not found media device.

Then in Device manager I do not see the Sound and Game controller device, instead i see something like:
[image]

I read online that this could be the problem, so tried to uninstall, disable these other/unknown devices. Restart the laptop. It did work for a while until the next reset, at which point these other devices appear back and Sound and game controller device disappeared and there is no audio output from laptop.

Any pointers on what could be wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you install all the drivers from HP, Chipset, Audio, Video, Card reader, etc?

Comment: No just audio? What are chipset drivers and why Card reader and Video? Webcam works fine?

Comment: Post your [full Product Number](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en)